# Access properties of a virtual class in partial class

Tags: c#, .net, class, object

```cs
public partial class IICustomer : IEntity
{
    public int CreatedByEmployeeId { get; set; }

    public virtual IItem IItem { get; set; }
}

public partial class IItem : IEntity
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to access `ItemName` through the object of `IICustomer`.

```cs
public void SaveIICustomers(int itemId, [FromBody] IEnumerable<CustomerDto> customers)
{
    IICustomer items = new IICustomer();

    items.IItem.ItemName="Sam"; // exception is thrown here
}
```

But the above code is throwing a `NullReferenceException`

> Object reference not set to instance of object.

Comment: It could be your `items.IItem` are null. You need to step into it to check. For the snippet you provide, `IICustomer` doesn't do anything on `IItem` when constructed.

Comment: Is there any other `partial` class definition of `IICustomer`?

Comment: From your code there is no telling if an instance of class `IItem` was created somewhere. Since it throws `NullReferenceException` allegedly the answer is 'no'

Comment: @Fabjan Do i have to create a separate object of  IItem like IItem it= new IItem();
Then how will i add that value to IICustomer object?

Comment: Image that there is a person that has address of another person (property `FriendsAddress` in class `Person`). Now imagine that the address does not exist but you still ask the compiler 'hey please change the address.country to US', guess what is going to happen ?

Comment: Also an out of topic recommendation is to avoid to add `I` letter before the class name because in most of the languages `I` letter is reserved for the interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because your object `items.IItem` is not yet created, it's null. Only object `items` is create.
If you want to create also the `IItem` object when your `item` object is created I recommend you to add an constructor into the class `IICustomer` like that:

```
public partial class IICustomer : IEntity
{
    public IICustomer(){
        IItem= new IItem();
    }
    public int CreatedByEmployeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual IItem IItem { get; set; }
}
```

In this way each time when you'll create an object `IICustomer` you will create also it's property `IItem`.